# Disable navigation drawer on groupItem Click In exapanablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I need to create a application in which i have navigation drawer with expandable list view. I want when i click any child item in group only drawer should open.

In my my case drawer is open in both case when i click on group and child item also.

Answer (score 0):

You just do this in your Actiivty  You just put this code in your onclick method..

mDrawerLayout  ---> Drawer Layout
mDrawerList    ---> List

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

(or) you want open drawer  means use this below one...

mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got my issue. I have wrote in some thing on group click listener. When i leave empty. I worked.

> private class DrawerGroupClickListener implements
>   OnGroupClickListener{
>
> ```
>   @Override       public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent,
> ```
>
> View v,
>                 int groupPosition, long id) {
>                         return false;       }
>
> }